# Perl: Force hash in numeric order

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash, numeric

I am trying to display hash data in record number order (that is, sorted by hash keys). I have stored the records in a hash with an associated record number.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is some similar code that shows the issue

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use Time::HiRes;

my $rec = {};
my %Data;
my $recno = 1;

while ($recno <= 100) {
   $rec->{recno} = $recno;
   $rec->{dt} = qx/date/;

   $Data{ $rec->{recno} } = $rec;

   # Initialize
   Time::HiRes::sleep(0.2);
   $recno++;
   $rec = {};
}

my $count = keys %Data;
print "Found $count records\n";

foreach my $rec (sort { $Data{$a} <=> $Data{$b} } keys %Data) {
#foreach my $rec (sort { $Data{$a} cmp $Data{$b} } keys %Data) {
  print "   Rec No: --".$rec."--\n";
  print "     Date: ". $Data{$rec}{dt}."\n";
}
```

Sometimes it does display the hash in order, sometimes it does not. Somewhat related to the number of records it looks like.

```
Found 100 records
   Rec No: --1--
     Date: Thu Feb 13 15:19:46 UTC 2020

   Rec No: --31--
     Date: Thu Feb 13 15:19:52 UTC 2020

   Rec No: --32--
     Date: Thu Feb 13 15:19:52 UTC 2020

   Rec No: --33--
     Date: Thu Feb 13 15:19:52 UTC 2020

   Rec No: --34--
     Date: Thu Feb 13 15:19:52 UTC 2020

   Rec No: --35--
     Date: Thu Feb 13 15:19:52 UTC 2020

   Rec No: --36--
     Date: Thu Feb 13 15:19:53 UTC 2020
```

Comment: Do you want to compare the values or the keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing the values, but you need to compare the keys:

```
for my $rec (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %Data) {
```

Comment: and the values are hash references, which are an arbitrary memory address in numeric context, not something it is useful to sort on

Answer (score 1):

See the answer by @choroba for a fix of the problem as you stated it.

But to have the problem not arise in the first place, **choose the optimal data structure for the task**. In this case, **you need an array, not a hash**. I also used more descriptive variable names and lowercase identifiers (see Conway (2005)).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Time::HiRes;

my $delay = 0.2;
my $num_dates = 100;
my @dates;

for ( 0 .. ($num_dates - 1) ) {   
   chomp( my $date = `date` );
   push @dates, $date;
   Time::HiRes::sleep($delay);
}

for ( 0..$#dates ) {
    print join( "\t", $_, $dates[$_] ), "\n";
}
```

**REFERENCE:**

Damian Conway. (2005) Perl Best Practices: Standards and Styles for Developing Maintainable Code. O'Reilly Media: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001735.do

Comment: Thanks for the response. My actual issue is much more complicated than the snippet I provided here and as such was much easier for me to read and I think to maintain, the way i did it.

Comment: Sometimes the combination of an array and hash is the optimal solution as well. For example, a hash to look up the data from the key, and an array to specify what order to evaluate the keys in.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly corrected code produces expected result.

NOTE: `date` in Windows require option `/T` otherwise it waits for user input

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::HiRes;

my $debug = 0;                  # debug flag

my %Data;
my($rec_id,$record);            # declared here for format
my $num_records = 100;          # define number of records

foreach my $recno (1..$num_records) {
    say "Record: $recno" if $debug;

    my $rec = {};

    $rec->{recno} = $recno;
    $rec->{dt} = qx/date \/T/;  # /T required for Windows 

    $Data{ $rec->{recno} } = $rec;

    # Initialize
    Time::HiRes::sleep(0.2);
    $recno++;
    $rec = {};
}

my $count = keys %Data;
say  "Total $count records";

$~ = 'STDOUT_HEAD';
write;
$~ = 'STDOUT';

foreach $rec_id (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %Data) {
    $record = $Data{$rec_id}{dt};
    write;
}

$~ = 'STDOUT_BOTTOM';
write;

format STDOUT_HEAD =
+------+------------------------------+
| No.  | Record                       |
+------+------------------------------+
.

format STDOUT =
| @>>> | @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< |
$rec_id, $record
.

format STDOUT_BOTTOM =
+------+------------------------------+
.
```

Output

```
Total 100 records
+------+------------------------------+
| No.  | Record                       |
+------+------------------------------+
|    1 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|    2 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|    3 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|    4 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|    5 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|    6 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|    7 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|    8 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|    9 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|   10 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
.......................................
.......................................
|   95 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|   96 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|   97 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|   98 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|   99 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
|  100 | Thu 02/13/2020               |
+------+------------------------------+
```